# Difference between "/" and "!/" in Slim

Tags: html, comments, slim

As far as I can see, a piece of code like:

```
/ This is a comment that will never get displayed, even in the source code
```

Will never be seen, and so seems to have no use?  Why would a person ever use it when there is

```
/! This is a comment that will only get displayed in the source code
```

Which will comment the code when it is compiled to HTML.

Is there something that I am not getting?  Why would anyone make an invisible comment?

Comment: I'm not sure if I am using the "comments" tag correctly, I mean comments in code, not comments wanted =)

Comment: Where did you get those samples from?

Comment: I got the information from [here](http://rdoc.info/gems/slim/frames).  The section is called "code comment /".  You can just find that text either using ctrl+f or looking down the contents page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean `/!` - you had them the other way around in your example.

`/!` [produces an HTML comment](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#HTML_comment___)

`/` [produces a comment in the code which doesn't compile to HTML](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Code_comment__)

Sometimes you want to published your comments so the outside world can see them. Code copyright, attribution or legal notices would be a good example of comments you want everyone to see when this compiles to HTML.

Code comments stay in your slim templates so will only be visible by people working with the template. Since comments are usually there to help developers and people working with the code rather than the general public, it makes sense to not compile most of this stuff into HTML. So "invisible" comments are actually visible to the people that need to see them.

Comment: Thanks for this, extremely helpful!  I'll also edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

The "invisible" comment will be seen by the coder reading the slim template, so it can be useful for a future coder to understand why you did something. This comment won't be seen by anyone checking the generated html source code once the page is online.

The other type of comment will also add html comments, so thru will be visible online.